# MVC 4 C# .net 4 Razor Controller Edit Viewmodel null value

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my Viewmodel I do a find of the id that is passed for the edit link. If I use the fields in that model, I sometimes get an error if the value is null and sometimes don't. I get an error on the same field, nvarchar(100), and other fields, nchar(10), I don't get the error. I don't know why, other than maybe the nchar(10) nulls are being treated differently?

```
        ViewBag.TimeRec = Time.Min + "-" + Time.Max +
            "-" + Time.Rate.ToString() + "-" +
            Time.Description.ToString().Trim();
```

The Time.Min and Max are both null, in the mssql DB table they are nchar(10), the Description is also null nvarchar(100). When I change it to test the Description and then replace it with a variable that contains "", no error is thrown.

I did a search and can't find any answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included how your mapping from sql to C#, but as a general case sql nchar[10] is always a string of 10 characters while nvarchar(10) is up-to 10 characters (including null).

This explains the difference between the nullable-nchar vs nullable-nvarchar

You can use null-coalescing operator (as per other answer) or you could add a string extension, such as:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimNull(this string value)
    {
        if (value == null) return string.Empty;
        return value.Trim();
    }
}
```

[name appropriately, if TrimOrEmptyIfNull (to match similar CLR IsNullOrWhiteSpace) ]

then use ... `+ Time.Description.TrimNull() +` ...

I would probably fix this in the mapping directly rather than force the UI developer to remember this every time.

Answer (score 0):

you get an error when you do .ToString() on Null

Answer (score 0):

use ?? (null-coalescing) operator to avoid null reference exception

```
(Time.Description??"").Trim()
```

You can learn more at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've used extension methods to address this in the past.

```
public static string EmptyIfNull(this object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        return value.ToString();
    }
```

Then you would be able to do the following:

```
Time.Description.EmptyIfNull()
```

You may also want to consider setting the default value for these fields to an empty string. Then you don't have to worry about null values.

Here is the code for the migration

```
AlterColumn("dbo.TableName", "ColumnName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 60, defaultValue: ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the value straight from the model in MVC4. I'm aware of testing for null though. In straight .net (at least for VB) I've always been able to use .ToString() and it converted null to spaces. I have no problem testing for null, now that I know, just wanted to make sure that the nchar and nvarchar were handled differently. Thanks